# How to resolve module dependancies when mocking modules in JEST

Tags: typescript, jestjs, node-modules

I have a `node` module resolution. And have a next modules:

```
A/
  A.tsx
  index.ts
B/
  B.tsx
  index.ts
  text.tsx
```

```
// A/A.tsx

export const A = '1'
```

```
// A/index.tsx

export {A} from 'A'
```

so, the `B.tsx` includes `A.tsx`:

```
// B.tsx


include {A} from '../A'

// ...usage
```

now, I want to cover `B` by UT. I use jest for it.

So, throughout testing, I want to mock `A` module. I can do it using several ways:

1. Redefine directly in the test file:

```
//test.tsx


jest.mock('../A', () => ({
  A: () => <div id='A' />
}))
```

That's works!

2. Create a mock file inside `__mocks__` folder

So, I have to create a `__mocks__` folder at the same level as `A` folder and create `A.tsx` file inside.

```
__mocks__/
A/
B/
```

and include that mock inside the test:

```
// test.tsx


jest.mock('../A')
```

So, that approach does not work. And, seems, it does not work due to module resolution, because if I include `A` module directly, like:

```
// B.tsx

import {A} from '../A/A'
```

and move mock-file `A.tsx` to `A/__mocks__/A.tsx`

and change mocking:

```
// test.tsx


jest.mock('../A/A')
```

then, everything works properly.

So, the task is to fix module resolution somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Node tries to resolve this module:

```
../A
```

...and detects that it is [a folder that doesn't have a `package.json` so it loads `index.js`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules).

This means that this line:

```
../A
```

...can also be written like this:

```
../A/index
```

So to create a [Manual Mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules) you should create your mock here:

```
../A/__mocks__/index.ts
```

...and that mock will be used when you call this in your test:

```
jest.mock('../A');  // <= uses the mock at ../A/__mocks__/index.ts
```